# How to change the default code colour theme on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, design, syntax-highlighting, firefox

I understand that Stack Exchange is using Google Prettify as its engine. I don't like the default them and I found some colour themes for it.

I did try it myself first and when I import my `.css` file at style editor on Firefox it does change the page with my theme but only for one page, not the whole site.

I don't want to do this routine for every page so can a user automatically  override the Stack Exchange `.css` theme for every page?

Comment: Better search on stackapps.com: http://stackapps.com/search?q=theme  but the answer is: There is no such feature built-in the site. You have to rely on third-party (browser) plugins

Comment: stylish, maybe?